# Change App Service Plan from Isolated to Isolated V2 Plan for a Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice, app-service-environment

We want to change the App Service Plan of an existing Azure Web App, from **Isolated Service Plan** to **Isolated "v2" Service Plan**. There are no changes in Subscription, Resource Group or Region. One condition for us is, we want to continue using same the Web App with the Plan alone changed. Please let me if this possible and how can we change this.

- I could see the "Change App Service Plan" option in Azure Portal but I am unable to exactly find it out regarding the Plan change by dabbling in it.
- We are able to create the required Isolated V2 Plan separately but we are unable to switch the Web App to the new Plan so far.
- Referring the Microsoft documentation, I keep coming across that different kinds of App Service Environments(ASE) are used for the above Plans, it is not clear due to different ASEs, the Plan change is possible or not.

For quick reference, I have sketched out my query below:

> Azure Web App        : Web-App-1
> App Service Plan     : **Isolated Service Plan**

to

> Azure Web App        : Web-App-1
> App Service Plan     : **Isolated V2 Service Plan**
> (Same Region, Subscription and Resource Group)

Comment: You can try the following: (1) Provision the new Isolated V2 Service Plan; (2) Export the existent WebApp ARM template in Azure Portal; (3) Edit the reference to the new App Service Plan in a text editor; (4) Deploy it via Azure Portal "Deploy a custom template". CAUTION: You should try this in a non production environment first to mitigate the risk of undesired results/side effects.

Comment: @EvandrodePaula that's a great idea

Answer (score 1):

when you try and change to the new ASP, Azure will perform a check to see if it is a valid move, so as long as you can see it in the destination combo box uner the change app service plan option you can try and let azure evaulate if the move is possible.

If you cannot see it as a destination then you might be able to clone the ASP because the two ASP's you have might be in a different webspace which you cannot do anything about.

Answer (score 1):

> Change App Service Plan from Isolated to Isolated V2 Plan for a Web App
> I keep coming across that different kinds of App Service Environments(ASE) are used for the above Plans, it is not clear due to different ASEs, the Plan change is possible or not.

- The private environment used with an Isolated plan is called the ***App Service Environment v2*** and with Isolated v2 Service Plan is called the **App Service Environment v3.**
- Apps can only move between plans that are created in the same webspace, where webspace is a internal deployment unit of App Service Plan.
- Apps cannot be moved between plans in different App Service Environments.
- Make sure you created the **App Service Environment v3** to change your web app to **Isolated V2 SKU.**

To know more information on changing the app service plans along with its SKU Sizes and its limitations, please refer this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage) and regarding the app service environments versions of Isolated Plans, refer [App Service pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/windows/).